# Can ionic ionViewDidEnter detect pop vs setRoot?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 page that needs to refresh the page's data if it is entered from a `navCtrl.setRoot()` but not if the page is being returned to via a `navCtrl.pop()`. I am using `ionViewDidEnter()` to detect when the page is being entered but can't work out how to distinguish between entry from `setRoot()` and entry from `pop()`.

My project is a Tabs project so the `setRoot()` comes every time the page's tab is selected.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

You need to use [**Events**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) here.You need to `Override` `back button` event as shown below.

*.ts*

```
@ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e: UIEvent) => {//override back button
      this.events.publish(Handlers.NEW_PROJECT_PAGE_BUDGET_HANDLER, this.data);
      this.navCtrl.pop();
    }
  }
```

**Old Answer:**

`navCtrl.setRoot()` means it push a new page to the navigation stack. So you can use `constructor()` of the page or `ionViewDidLoad() - This event only happens once per page being created`.

`navCtrl.pop()` means you can use only the `ionViewDidEnter() - Runs when the page has fully entered and is now the active page. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.` to detect (or fire) it since it uses `the cached` page.

Comment: I am using a Tabs project. Every time the page is selected via a Tab I want to reload the data, but every time the page is entered via a pop(back) I want to just show the previous state of the page.

Comment: Still, you can use above mentioned `events` no? Any issue?

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding? ionViewDidLoad() only runs the first time the page is launched via a Tab. Every subsequent time I only get ionViewDidEnter() so I can't then distinguish between a Tab setRoot and a pop from clicking on a back button.

Comment: See the **Update**

Comment: Ah ok. I was wondering if there was a way to do this without events.

Comment: You cannot do it since `ionViewDidEnter()` event fires on both situations.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought. But it was worth asking just in case I had missed something.

Comment: You didn't miss anything here :D

Comment: Thanks @Sampath :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)